# ggplotsurv showing error of differing number of rows in shiny

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny, survival-analysis

I am building a shiny app in R trying to plot reactive survival curves from survfit object using ggsurvplot, but it shows the error as following:

```
Warning: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 4893, 0, 9786
Stack trace (innermost first):
    106: data.frame
    105: cbind
    104: cbind
    103: surv_summary
    102: <Anonymous>
    101: do.call
    100: ggsurvplot
```

The server code is:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
   cox <- reactive({
    survfit(as.formula(paste("Surv(GTIME,GSTATUS) ~ ",paste(input$Feature))), data=olt)
  })

  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    ggsurvplot(
      cox(),  
      data = olt, 
      risk.table = FALSE, 
      pval = TRUE
    )
  })
}
```

I have searched about the error of differing number of rows in ggplot, but 
the function works well and is able to plot the survival curves when it is not in the shiny app so I am not sure what causes the error here. Does anyone have seen this error in shiny before?

Any info is appreciated!

Comment: You're not showing the data.frame so your code means nothing.

Comment: Consider putting in a debugging call to `cat` (or the shiny message function) to output the structure of your data.frame and the value of `input$Feature`

Comment: Thank you @J0ki for your comments! I was trying to figure out how to show the data.frame but not sure how to use a debugging call to output the structure of the data.frame

Comment: @42-Thank you for your comment. Do you know how to use a debugging call to output the data.frame?